# Why Visual Studio Code can't compile my C code?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have a problem which is: VSC can't compile my C code as the title said. I have looked for the problems and did all what was necessary:

- installed msys
- installed mingw
- installed C/C++ extensions
- added code runner

Yet the problem is still showing like this:

```
gcc.exe: error: name.c: No such file or directory
```

(Note that I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to using VSC and don't have any background in coding so I'd appreciate it if I get to know the solution by simple vocabulary :) )

Comment: The toolchain seems to be ok, the file is not found, is it called `name.c`?

Comment: Also, show the compilation line that should appear in the output

Comment: yea i named it "name" . and the code was simply a hello world script . nothing complex

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your c file('name.c') is not located in your working directory.

Moving your c file to your project folder may solve your problem.

To check your working directory, choose terminal tab and type 'pwd'.

Comment: I'm using windows not linux and I thought vsc doesn't force a project folder like vs so my files location should not matter. isn't it ?